# Google Finance get year to date spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-finance

I'm using Google Sheets to get stock data from Google Finance, how can I get Year to day percentage change?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Google and an entire year please try:

```
=100*(googlefinance("GOOG")/index(googlefinance("GOOG","price",today()-365),2,2)-1)
```

Or, for this year-to-date:

```
=100*(googlefinance("GOOG","price")/index(googlefinance("GOOG","price",date(2018,12,31)),2,2)-1)
```

Comment: That's 1 year change, not year to date. (first day of the year to now )
So... I made this =100*(googlefinance($A5)/index(googlefinance($A5,"price",date(2019,1,1)),2,2)-1)  - But there is a small change in price.